# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) message when i host my page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-hosting

My js file doesnt seem to work and i get the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" message. I cant understand why. Also it works fine until I host the page on public server.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is better use public folder to store the js and css files. certain servers only give access privilage to public folder

Comment: no problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use relative path like:

```
<script type="..." src="./JavaScript/app.js"></script>
```